# What is Business logic in Clean Architecture (domain)

Tags: android, business-logic, clean-architecture

People say business logic should handled in domain layer.

But I don't exactly understand what is business logic in Android.

In my project I cache data when API request is successful.
And if API Request got failed, get local data.

In my understand It can be a kind of business rule.
1. API request
2. If API request is failed load data from local.

I think this logic should be done in the repository.
But business logic should handle in domain layer.

Am I misunderstanding the business logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The business logic is refereed to `if`s and `else`s you have after you receive the data from the API. Let's say that you want to load an image using `Picasso`. The url is:

> https://.../imageId.jpg

But first you will need to fetch this object which has an id attached to it's JSON:

```
{
 "id" : "1234123",
 "name" : "SomeName"
}
```

Well, first you would need to fetch this:

```
val request = repository.fetchTheObject()
//let's assume the result is successful
//start of the business logic
val imageId = request.id
if(id == WHATEVER){
val url = "someUrl/${id}.jpg"
someMutableLiveData.postValue(url)
}else{
 showSomeError()    
}
//end of business logic
```

And then in your fragment you just receive the final result:

```
viewModel.someMutableLiveData.observe(this, Observer{
  Picasso.get().load(it).into(imageView)
})
```

In other words:

Business logic is all the actions you need to perform to the data you receive from the source of truth (database, files, network API etc) in order to achieve a desirable result

In case of Android:

- `Fragment`/`Activity` for interacting with the user
- `ViewModel` for business logic (sometimes when you have tones of `if`s/`else`, a lot of for-loops etc, Google suggests to use a Presenter attached to a ViewModel, never done it)
- Repository, just a source to receive the data (even though sometimes it's redundant, like when you have only one source of truth)

In your case the business logic is exactly what you describe: If your request fails then get local data, this is a business logic of the app.

> I think this logic should be done in the repository.

Well you can do that, and I have seen many examples like that and it really depends, sometimes could be correct. But in case when you are using a `ViewModel` in order to avoid all `Transformations` you can just handle it in the `ViewModel` instead of the `Repository`.